# Heroku mysql version issue

Tags: mysql, heroku, migration

I am using mysql 5.6 on my local machine for my laravel app and Heroku is on 5.5 meaning Ì am getting an error in production :

```
General error: 1293 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause.
```

I suppose I can't upgrade the mysql version on Heroku so is there a way around this ?

Comment: Heroku doesn't have their own MySQL offering. Which of the various third-party options at https://elements.heroku.com/search/addons?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mysql are you using? https://elements.heroku.com/addons/jawsdb or https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cleardb ?

Comment: oh sorry I am using ClearDB sql

Comment: Looks like you're SOL with ClearDB. https://getsatisfaction.com/cleardb/topics/cleardb-mysql-version-issue I can't find anything on the JawsDB version. Heroku is really more focused on Postgres. You could start up an AWS RDS MySQL instance and connect directly to it, if you like.

Comment: Ok well I solved it when I changed my production DB to postgres. thx